# Can I force Eclipse to run full builds on file save?

Tags: eclipse

I've run up against [a bug relating to the Eclipse incremental compiler](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/156) that isn't a problem on full builds, either from within the IDE or on the command line. I like not having to manually invoke a build, but the automatic build seems to only invoke the incremental compiler. Is there a way to have Eclipse still automatically build but run an inefficient, but correct, full build instead?